# React accessing props object startDate and endDate

Tags: reactjs

> Please, I want to access startDate and endDate. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Please include proper code snippet so that we can know what we are dealing with

Answer (score 0):

`days[1].props.startDate` to access start date
`days[1].props.endDate` to access end date

Answer (score 0):

`days` is an array of react elements with props `date`,`startDate`, ... as a instance of `Moment` class. To display you need to format it. Example:

```
moment(days[1].props.startDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
```